# Python 3 clean and normalize URL list

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, normalization, normalize

I have a list of URL in a text file and I need using Python 3 run a function so that the URL's would match the format of https://www.google.com/images/

An example of the list:

```
http://www.google.com/images/<text>
https://ca.google.com/images/<text>
https://www.google.com/images/<text>
http://uk.google.com/images/<text>
https://www.google.com/images/<text>
```

I would need to make a script that would read through the file, clean the URL so for example the URL http://www.google.com/images/ will change to https://www.google.com/images/ and would replace the country code with `www` as well. So, if it is `http://ca.google.com` It should change to `https://www.google.com`

May I ask what tools should I use to detect incorrect URL's so I could locate them, fix them and save to the file?

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Current code:

```
urls = open("urls.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8')
urls = [item.replace('http://', 'https://') for item in urls]
for item in urls:
    if not 'www' in item:
        old_item = item
        v = str(item[8:10])
        new_item = item.replace(v, 'www')
        urls.append(new_item)
        urls.remove(old_item)
print(urls)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since strings are immutable in python we can't change alphabets in them but make new strings, hence the slight complication. First we remove the `http` elements. Then we check if `www` is present in the link or not. If not we replace the country code(two alphabets) with `www`

```
list1 = ['http://www.google.com/images', 'https://ca.google.com/images','https://www.google.com/images','http://uk.google.com/images',
'https://www.google.com/images']
list1 = [item.replace('http://', 'https://') for item in list1]
for item in list1:
    if not 'www' in item:
        old_item = item
        v = str(item[8:10])
        new_item = item.replace(v, 'www')
        list1.append(new_item)
        list1.remove(old_item)

print(list1)
```

Output:
`['https://www.google.com/images', 'https://www.google.com/images', 'https://www.google.com/images', 'https://www.google.com/images', 'https://www.google.com/images']`

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking a look! Well, on the list, sometimes instead of www there is uk or ca or any kind of country code, therefore, I would need to automatically change it to www without knowing what country code it is, perhaps there is a way to just change the beginning of the string?

Comment: @Dave if there are only 3 , 4 countries that repeat the best way would be to use the same code as above. Just add the abbreviation of the country and replace them with `www`. like so `list1 = [item.replace('ca', 'www') for item in list1]` . might be slightly repetitive and unpythonic but will get the job done. If there are numerous let me know, I will try.

Comment: Perhaps there is a way just to replace everything up until the symbol "."? I was thinking that maybe the best way is to replace everything until the mentioned symbol with "https://www". Currently, these URL's are in a text file, I can loop them, each of them is on a different line, so perhaps there is a way in Python to check if the URL does not start with https://www and if it does not I could replace it with https://www? Sorry if I am poor at explaining it but I think this solution might work but I don't know if this is possible and I was not able to find any examples of it. Thank you!

Comment: @Dave Yes of course there is. Give me some time. I will update the answer and let you know.

Comment: The thing is that there is a very big amount of URLs and I would not be able to write each of the countries, but still thank you for checking this out!

Comment: I have added to my question on how I read my text file, I hope this helps.

Comment: @Dave Updated the answer. Check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223720/discussion-between-dave-and-abrar-ahmed).